# ASP.NET MVC 5 how to use View from different class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to figure out how can I put my View in different class library. My View are located in class library named Presentation and the Controllers are in standard ASP.NET MVC 5 web aplication project.

I tried with the Custom ViewEngineProvider, listed below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Controllers
{
    public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomViewEngine() : base()
        {
            ViewLocationFormats = new[] 
            {
                "~/Views/{1}/%1/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Views/{1}/%1/{0}.vbhtml",
                "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
            };

            PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] 
            {
                "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
            };
        }

        protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
        {
            return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath);
        }

        protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
        {
            return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
        }

        protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
        {
            return base.FileExists(controllerContext, virtualPath);
        }

    }
}7
```

But this not works.
I read about VirtualPathProvider, but I cant figure out how it works and how to use it in this case, if it can solve my probelm.

thnx

Comment: https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator

Comment: thnx, but I would like learn how to do this with coding...

Comment: also tried RazorGenerator .... I cant made it to work
Folloed couple tutorials and not working

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Views are not compiled into class library because of they are static files, so you are not able to add reference to project which contains views.

When you are moving your Models, Views and Controllers to separate projects - usually Models and Controllers goes to separate and Views stays in ASP.NET MVC project.

But if you want to keeps it as it is now then you can add build event to your project and copy views from one project to another.

Or you can use RazorGenerator which will allows you to compile views.

Comment: KK, thnx, I change it then

Comment: Can u provide me some code how to migrate Controller in class library and how to use it, how to connect the whole thing.
thn